# egit, How to set up a repository on a web server, in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, git, repository, egit

I've managed to set up a repo on my local C drive, but I want to be able to set one up on a web server.
I can assess the server like this:
[image]

But what I want to do is this:
[image]

However, when I try and do that I get this:
[image]

When I should be getting this:
[image]

Which is what I get if I make a local repo on my C drive.

So my question is, how can I use my web server a repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FTP isn't supported as transfer protocol with EGit (and not even for Git). So you have to use another protocol or use a service like Github or Gitorious.

Comment: I'm trying at the moment to use Drop Box, I'll let you know of any success.